# How to add content (books and music) into my library so I can sync it with my mobile devices?

Tags: catalina, data-synchronization

I am having trouble synching my books (non-DRMed epub/pdf) and music (non-DRMed m4a) to my iPad.

I've seen guides (like this one: https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mchl562e1847/mac) on how to sync via finder. BUT what I cannot find is a guide on how to add things into my library so I can then sync them into my device.

As a test, I've added some books into the Books app but nothing shows up in Finder/books sync. I've unplugged/replugged the iPad several times already just to check if that makes a difference.

Can you please help? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I rarely use books so I'm going from old data, but I *think* you just drag the book into the Books.app window. The picture in your question shows where you can change individual books ability to sync, etc. As for music, drag any music files (or their containing folder into the iTunes/Music window. I usually select songs in the left hand pane before doing this so I can verify the songs are there and make any changes as soon as they finish copying. Once that is done you can sync the device.

Comment: Do you have icloud set up?